# Split a string with RegEx

Tags: python, regex, split

Good time of the day,

Currently I am little bit stuck on a challenge.
I have to make a word count within a phrase, I have to split it by empty spaces or any special cases present.

```
import re

def word_count(string):
    counts = dict()
    regex = re.split(r" +|[\s+,._:+!&@$%^]",string)
    for word in regex:
        word = str(word) if word.isdigit() else word
        if word not in counts:
            counts[word] = 1
        else:
            counts[word] += 1
    return counts
```

However I am stuck at Regex part.
While splitting, empty space are taken also in account

I started with using

```
for word in string.split():
```

But it does not pass the test wiht phrases such as:

"**car : carpet as java : javascript!!&@$%^&**"

"**hey,my_spacebar_is_broken.**"

'**досвидания!**'

Hence, if I understand, RegEx is needed.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `str(word) if word.isdigit() else word` does nothing

Comment: I don't quite understand the goal.  Are you trying to count the alphanumeric substrings (calling these words) which are separated by non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However it happens that I calculate empty space as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Olvin Roght for his suggestions. Your function can be elegantly reduced to this.

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

def word_count(text):
    count=Counter(re.split(r"[\W_]+",text))
    del count[''] 
    return count
```

See Ryszard Czech's answer for an equivalent one liner.

Comment: Thank you folks, though word_count("hey,my_spacebar_is_broken.") -> {'hey': 1, 'my': 1, 'spacebar': 1, 'is': 1, 'broken': 1, '': 1}. For some reason it still calculates an empty space

Comment: @SergiyPolovynko, it's empty string, not empty space and it occures on the end of source string between last dot and end of line. If you'll add some random text to the end of your string or remove dot, it'll disappear.

Comment: I added one line to ensure that the count of empty strings are excluded

Comment: +1, but if you use findall, you would not need to remove empty items. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67492392/11329890.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

def word_count(text):
    return Counter(re.findall(r"[^\W_]+",text))
```

`[^\W_]+` matches one or more characters different from non-word and underscore chars. This matches one or more letters or digits in effect.

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/XsSjXE/1).

Answer (score 0):

Change the regex pattern as below. No need to use `' +|` in the pattern as you are already using `'\s'`. Also, note the `'+'`.

```
regex = re.split(r"[\s+,._:+!&@$%^]+", string)
```